# How can I satisfy the warning about no rubyforge_project specified?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I build a gem, I get

```
(in /home/agrimm/ruby/chaser)
WARNING:  no rubyforge_project specified
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: chaser
  Version: 0.0.2
  File: chaser-0.0.2.gem
```

[The friendly manual](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#rubyforge_project) says "Obviously, if your gem doesn’t have a Rubyforge project, leave this setting alone." (I don't have a Rubyforge project)

Trying to set `rubyforge_project` to `nil` still produced the warning, and setting it to `false` caused the build to fail.

Is there anything I can currently do about the warning, or should I just [wait](http://twitter.com/brynary/status/5469025292)?

Comment: Maybe it should be filed as a bug.

Answer (score 3):

I registered a project on RubyForge called "nowarning" to avoid this warning. Feel free to point to it by putting this in your gemspec:

```
s.rubyforge_project = "nowarning"
```

If the user ever manages to navigate to the project page they just get a note about going back to look at the home page. Have a look at http://rubyforge.org/projects/nowarning/

Feel free to suggest any copy updates for the description on that page.

Answer (score 2):

Just ignore it. It's harmless, and eventually it will go away.